# Layout out data-entry form in HTML: table or no table?

Tags: html

I want to create a data-entry form like the following:

```
Name:    [ Name textbox ]
Age:     [ Age textbox  ]
label n: [ textbox n    ]
```

Where the labels left-align, and the textboxes left-align.  I know I can do this in a `table` element, but I'm also aware that "tables should only be for tabular data".  While I part agree/disagree with that statement - I'd like to know whether my desired layout could/should be considered "tabular data", and what an alternative layout would be to produce the same results without dozens of lines of complicated cross-browser CSS.

I don't do web development much at the moment (strictly WinForms for some time now when I do UI work), so I appreciate there may be an elegant solution.  Possibly involving an unordered list with the bullet points turned off and a bit off label->field y position offsetting, perhaps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unordered lists with `label` elements should be the way to go here. The markup I would use should look something like:

```
<form id="person" method="post" action="process.php">
    <ul>
        <li><label for="name">Name: </label><input id="name" name="name" type="text" /></li>
        <li><label for="age">Age: </label><input id="age" name="age" type="text" /></li>
        <li><label for="n">N: </label><input id="n" name="n" type="text" /></li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

And this CSS if to get something similar to want you asked for:

```
#person ul {
    list-style: none;
}

#person li {
    padding: 5px 10px;
}

#person li label {
    float: left;
    width: 50px;
    margin-top: 3px;
}

#person li input[type="text"] {
    border: 1px solid #999;
    padding: 3px;
    width: 180px;
}
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/tZhUQ/1 , which contains some more interesting stuff you can try.

Comment: The input[type="text"] selector won't work in IE6 if that's a requirement.

Answer (score 1):

[Webcredible have an example](http://www.webcredible.co.uk/user-friendly-resources/css/css-forms.shtml), just remove the `text-align: right` to get what you appear to be looking for.

[Smashing Magazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2006/11/11/css-based-forms-modern-solutions/) and [Design Shack](http://designshack.co.uk/articles/10-css-form-examples) have collated some examples.